# php mysql categories tree ul

Tags: php, treeview

I created a php function to show categories tree but I am having trouble getting the output that I need.

HTML output needed:

```
   <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Main menu</a>
           <ul>
              <li class="has-child-menu"><a href="#">Second Level</a>
           <ul class="thired-level">
              <li><a href="index.html">Thired Level 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.html">Thired Level 2</a></li>
           </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
          </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my function to get categories from database

```
 function categoryTree($parent_id = 0){
        global $db;
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = $parent_id ");

        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                echo $row['category_name'];
                categoryTree($row['id'] );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? What does the data look like? Where are the `<ul>`s and `<li>`s in your code?

Comment: I don't know where to use <ul> s and <li> s to get my needed output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function to create a flat array of the data from the database:

```
function readData ($db) 
{
    $data  = [];
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = $parent_id ");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Then you need a recursive function to build your nested array as follow:

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = [];

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

Finally, you will call the functions respectively:

```
$data = readData();
$tree = buildTree($data);
```

Comment: I'm a beginner please complete the code if possible